# Why does Laravel say I am logged out if I am not?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have been trying to check if I am logged in with `Auth::guard('api')->check()` in `VuePostController.php`.

If I `dd()` it then I will get `false` back while I am logged in.

I am trying to check if I am logged in because I have been unable to check user `id` to make posts in my Vue view. I am using Api calls in `api.php`.

#### VuePostController.php (create function only)

```php
$post = new Posts();
$post->title = $request->get('title');
$post->body = $request->get('body');
$post->slug = Str::slug($post->title);

dd(Auth::guard('api')->check());

if ($post->save()) {
    return new PostResource($post);
}
```

#### api.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Posts\VuePostController;

Route::get('posts', [VuePostController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('post/{id}', [VuePostController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('post', [VuePostController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('post', [VuePostController::class, 'store']);
Route::delete('post/{id}', [VuePostController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Comment: How do you know you are logged in ? Do not confuse `guard('api')` with `guard('web')` so what are you using for API authentication ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I know im logged in because otherwise i couldn't access the page. there is a middleware around web.php that doesn't let u go anywhere without being logged in. And besides that it literally shows logged in username and id on the post page that i was talking about.

Comment: @ChrisServ `web.php` doesn't use the `api` guard, though.

Comment: As @ChrisServ stated, you are confusing `api` with `web`, those are 2 different guards. One is for normal web operations as you are already logged in, but `api` is for `/api` routes (you can modify this behavior) so you still need to _log in_ there or use some sort of authentication, like `tokens`. So everything is working as expected in your code (nothing is wrong). You have to modify how your routes or "_log in_" on the API.

Comment: Ok so if im logged into the WEB.php im not logged in API.php, its different. So if i wanne login in api.php i have too use tokens with Sanctum i assume?